# Connecting to Amazon RDS with MySql Workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am setting up a webapp on aws with elasticbeanstalk. I am trying to manage the RDS database with mysql workbench.

I was able to successfully connect and I think I uploaded the tables using workbench but I see nothing on the webapp. Anyone see this before? I would provide more info if I knew what was useful to provide.

Comment: This question is very broad. The issue could be almost anything - permission errors, application issues, or some other configuration issue. My suggestion would be to check the logs of MySQL Workbench and your application to hopefully find some insights on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

ssh your EC2 machine which belongs to Elasticbean Stalk , and telnet your RDS or install MySQL client and try to make connection and list tables.